# How do you create controller specific view resolvers in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, struts

In Struts you often define success and failure views for a controller in the struts configuration file, such as:

```
<action path="/Home" type="org.sample.HomeAction">
<forward name="success" path="/views/Home.jsp"/>
<forward name="failure" path="/views/Error.jsp"/>
</action>
<action path="/AddCustomer" type="org.sample.AddCustomerAction">
<forward name="success" path="/views/AddCustomer.jsp"/>
<forward name="failure" path="/views/AddCustomerError.jsp"/>
</action>
```

If you do this, the same logical view names (success and failure) can resolve to different jsps depending on which controller they are called from. By contrast, in the simplest spring set up, the view resolver is global. What is the easiest way to replicate this kind of configuration in Spring MVC?

I know one way to do it is to use the SimpleFormController, which has the methods getFormView() and getSuccessView(), but I'd prefer not to have the restriction of having to inherit from that class. Is there a more general way to do controller specific view resolution?

The scenario I'm investigating is migrating a large amount of Struts code to Spring. The old code uses "success" and "failure" extensively. Ideally, I'd simply like to use an existing Spring view resolver and just replicate the same config. e.g.

```
<bean class="some.spring.view.resolver">
    <property>
        <controller name="org.sample.HomeAction">
             <view name="success" value="/views/Home.jsp"/>
             <view name="failure" value="/views/Error.jsp"/>
        </controller>
        <controller name="org.sample.AddCustomerAction">
             <view name="success" value="/views/AddCustomer.jsp"/>
             <view name="failure" value="/views/AddCustomerError.jsp"/>
        </controller>               
</bean>
```

Is there an existing Spring view resolver that supports having the same logical view names resolving to different values depending on which controller they are called from? Or do I need to write my own or update the logical view names to be globally unique?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a different view name from your controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {

  try {
   // Some logic

   return "home";
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return "error";
  }
}
```

this will resolve the appropriate jsp view depending on the result of calling the controller method. This is very similar to the the struts2 approach of returning a string representing the result of the action method, you just don't need the extra xml to map the result string to the jsp view.

Comment: How are you suggesting that home and error will be resolved to actual views? How will they resolve to different jsps depending on what controller the logic names are called from? e.g. if "error" is called from the Home controller it might go to "homeError.jsp" but if "error" is called from the CustomerFormController it might go to "customerFormError.jsp".

Comment: Home and error will be resolved to views by the standard spring view resolvers. If you need different jsps for each controller you just return a different string. There is no need to use home and error. You can use customerformerror and homeerror etc.

Comment: All you're really doing is moving the logic that struts holds in xml into your controller methods. I consider that to be a massive improvement.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see how this allows the same logical view names to resolve to different views from different controllers? I need "success" to resolve to one thing from one controller, and a different thing from another controller. How are saying that happens?

Comment: I'm saying that instead of using the String 'success' etc. You use the actual view name that you want to resolve.